# Make “aviation” and “airplanes” tag synonyms

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

Please make [airplanes](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airplanes) and [aviation](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aviation) synonyms, preferably under **aviation**. Otherwise questions [get tagged doubly](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/1118/82).

Comment: By the way, is this a `feature-request` or `support`? And is asking a meta question appropriate or should this be dealt with using moderator flags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created the synonym and merged the tags. [support](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support) is fine for this. For simple synonyms that don't need discussion it would be enough to just @notify us mods in chat. If it is a bit more complicated, a meta topic is certainly useful.